# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am a beginner in ASP.NET Core. I am creating a Web API service. While I am fetching the data from the database, I had a problem. What is the error I got? I have successfully done the database migration part and created the database successfully.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'webb.StudentDbContext' while attempting to activate 'webb.Controllers.StudentController'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method3(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )

`StudentController`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    private StudentDbContext studentDbContext;

    public StudentController(StudentDbContext studentDbContext)
    {
        studentDbContext = studentDbContext;
    }

    // GET: api/<EmployeeController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
    {
        return studentDbContext.Student;
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
namespace webb.Model
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int stname { get; set; }

        public int course { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`StudentDbContext`:

```
 public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }

     public StudentDbContext()
     {
     }

     public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
     {
     }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(e => e.id);
     }

     protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
     {
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sms;Integrated Security=True; TrustServerCertificate = True");
     }
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "StudentConnStr": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sms;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

Where I am going to set the key.

`Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using webb;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StudentDbContext")));

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: What's your startup.cs looks like ? How you register the dbcontext?

Comment: i didn't add the startup.cs

Comment: You have the Program.cs?

Comment: yes.............................

Comment: why this error is displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250732/discussion-between-qing-guo-and-abi-jega).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are missing out inject `StudentDbContext` which is the DbContext to DI container.

Add below to your Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StudentConnStr")));
```

refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#dependency-injection-services)  and [Part 5, work with a database in an ASP.NET Core MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

**Update**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StudentConnStr")));

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: builder.Configuration    this line getting error

Comment: @abi jega   What's error you get ?

Comment: Configuration is not null here

Comment: @abi jega Could you refer [Part 5, work with a database in an ASP.NET Core MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to set your ConectionString key from appsettings.json ?

Comment: i attached the appsettings.json where i going to set the key

Comment: @abi jega Please try my update code.

Comment: i tried i got the error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot modify ServiceCollection after application is built.'

Comment: @abijega Have you  add this code before `var app = builder.Build();` ?

Comment: yesssss..........................

Comment: i added the program.cs full code above

Comment: i have changed StudentDbContext

Comment: @abijega Please try my update. Note the code order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250725/discussion-between-abi-jega-and-qing-guo).

Answer (score 0):

`builder.Build()` should be after all `AddXXX` functions. In other words, you need to swap it with `AddDbContext()`

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
 options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StudentDbContext")));

var app = builder.Build();
```